# overflow:scrol doesn't show the scroll

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I am using asp.net 4

#### Problem

The scrol is not shown

#### asp code

```
<div id="tabs-1">
                        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />
                        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                            <ContentTemplate>
                                <table id="BookingTable" runat="server" class="tableResultClass">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>ID</th>
                                        <th>PlanTime</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </ContentTemplate>
                            <Triggers>
                                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="mealTimeSelector" />
                            </Triggers>
                        </asp:UpdatePanel>
                    </div>
```

#### the css of tableResultClass

```
.tableResultClass{
        overflow:scroll;
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background:#fefefe;
        width:90%;
        margin:5% auto 0;
        -moz-border-radius:5px; /* FF1+ */
        -webkit-border-radius:5px; /* Saf3-4 */
        border-radius:5px;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

#### The css of the parent

http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Does it have a height? It's not going to overflow if there's no height on there. Can you make a fiddle replicating the problem?

Comment: I will try to make a fiddle, alsthought it is asp.net not pure html

Comment: @Gareth I added this http://jsfiddle.net/eQhTE/ , put I didn't know how to add this external style, could you try please http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a div surrounding the table and apply the CSS class to that div. Overflow doesn't apply to tables.

Comment: i already tried that, i applied the overflow for the parent div but i got only a bar not a scrol,

Comment: and this bar is not scrolable not nice

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli You can apply: `overflow-x: scroll` so you can only have the bottom scrollbar show.